# Personal Drawing Board

Tags: software-rec, application, notes

I am a computer science major who has a lot of theoretical classes that involve a lot of math. I hate using pen and paper for scratch work because I keep on losing them so I am planning on getting a new bamboo input tablet so that I can do all the "scratch work" in an accessible format on my laptop. However, I am finding it hard locating an application in Linux that essentially acts as an accessible white board. All of the apps I look at are geared towards artists and so are not designed to accommodate my needs. Is there an app geared to people who have requirements like mine?

P.S I already use latex but that is usually for work already done and thus not very effective for the things that I am still figuring out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using [Xournal](http://xournal.sourceforge.net/):

> Xournal is an application for notetaking, sketching, keeping a journal using a stylus. It is free software (GNU GPL) and runs on Linux (recent distributions) and other GTK+/Gnome platforms. It is similar to Microsoft Windows Journal or to other alternatives such as Jarnal, Gournal, and NoteLab.

[image: Xournal screenshot]

Or if you don't mind a Java app, [Jarnal](http://jarnal.wikispaces.com/):

> Jarnal is an open-source application for notetaking, sketching, keeping a journal, making a presentation, annotating a document - including pdf - or collaborating using a stylus, mouse or keyboard. It is similar to Microsoft Windows Journal and to the earlier Mimeo whiteboarding and Palm notepad applications.

[image: Jarnal screenshot]

However, they are not so much of a whiteboard, but much more like note-taking applications.

Comment: You beat me to it, I thought of Xournal too when I saw the question but couldn't remember its name. I've used it before and it's pretty good for this kind of use.

Comment: I realize this is literally years later, but I wanted to do the right thing and mark your answer as the correct one!